# HOw to use dicriminator map in Doctrine Entity extended from abstract class in symfony2 php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this structure

```
`UserInterface.php`
 abstract class User implements UserInterfacee in model`
`class student extends user.php`
`class teacher extends user.php`
```

Now in which class should i use this doctrine code

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "student" = "Student"})
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Inheritance annotations in parent class.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"student" = "Student", "teacher" = "Teacher"})
 */
  class User
 {
 // ...
 }

  /** @Entity */
  class Student extends User
   {
    // ...
  }

  /** @Entity */
  class Teacher extends User
   {
    // ...
  }
```